# pyplot fill between error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have 2 array:

```
t1 = array([[963],
       [964],
       [965],
       [966]])

f1 = array([[ 3.52473569],
       [ 3.52473569],
       [ 3.52473569],
       [ 3.52473569]], dtype=float32)
```

These 2 arrays have the same length, same dimensions. However when I tried:

```
plt.fill_between(t1, f1)
```

I got this error :

```
  File "<ipython-input-126-986395e7c03f>", line 1, in <module>
    plt.fill_between(t1, f1)

  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2896, in fill_between
    **kwargs)

  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1818, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\opt\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4596, in fill_between
    raise ValueError("Argument dimensions are incompatible")

ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible
```

but t1 and f1 work in this command:

```
plt.fill(t1, f1)
```

Please tell me where the mistake is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are passing a nested list to `fill_between`. Try to flatten your list like this:

```
t1 = array([[963],
            [964],
            [965],
            [966]]).flatten()

f1 = array([[3.52473569],
            [3.52473569],
            [3.52473569],
            [3.52473569]], dtype=float).flatten()
```